# Why is the child route not showing when navigting to it?

Tags: angular

I am having the following routes:

```js
{path: 'group/:groupId', component: GroupComponent, data: {state: 'group'},
 children: [
   {path: 'voting/:votingId', component: VotingComponent, data: {state: 'voting'}, children: [
       {path: '', redirectTo: 'vote', pathMatch: 'full'},
       {path: 'vote', component: VoteComponent, data: {state: 'vote'}},
       {path: 'favorite-places', component: FavoritePlacesComponent, data: {state: 'favorite-places'}}
   ]}
 ]
},
```

However, for some reason the child routes are not being displayed.

If I navigate from https://localhost:4200/#/group/1 to https://localhost:4200/#/group/1/voting/1/vote, the component does not get displayed.

What does work is displaying `/group/1/voting/1/vote` in a nested `router-outler` but that's not what I want. I want it to show up in the "*current*" router outlet.

This is the main layout of the application:

```xml
<div class="main" [@applicationTransition]="applicationState">

  <nav class="header" [@headerTransition]="currentHeaderView">
    <div class="header-container">
      <ng-container #vcr></ng-container>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <main class="content" [@contentTransition]="openCloseState">
    <router-outlet #o="outlet"></router-outlet>
  </main>

</div>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? Can you reproduce with a [mcve] on StackBlitz?

Answer (score 0):

What you wrote there looks like it is correct.  Are you using any type of middle man to intercept the route action in order to issue an action to your store?  The reason I ask is when the router resolves the data element that you have in play there, it uses the name of the element to decide if it needs to keep it around.  If it has an element that it hasn't seen before, it will append it to the data collection on the RouterState.  If it has the exact same name, it will update that element.  I don't see where you are resolving your parameters here in the code.  Example of my code that has same number of children that works...

```
{
    path: 'batches/:batchId',
    resolve: { item: BatchResolver },
    data: {
      breadcrumb: 'Batches',
    },
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'edit', pathMatch: 'full' },
      {
        path: 'edit',
        component: BatchDetailsComponent,
        resolve: { breadcrumb: BatchBreadcrumbResolver },
      },
      {
        path: 'childbatches',
        component: BatchListComponent,
        resolve: { data: BatchChildBatchesResolver },
      },
      { path: 'childbatches/new', component: BatchAddComponent },
      {
        path: 'childbatches/:childbatchesId',
        children: [
          { path: '', redirectTo: 'edit', pathMatch: 'full' },
          { path: 'edit', component: BatchDetailsComponent },
          { path: 'childbatches/new', component: BatchAddComponent },
        ],
        resolve: { item: BatchResolver },
      },
    ],
  },`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the component from the `voting/:votingid` route and making it a "component-less" route.

```
{path: 'group/:groupId', component: GroupComponent, data: {state: 'group'},
 children: [
   {path: 'voting/:votingId', data: {state: 'voting'}, children: [
       {path: '', redirectTo: 'vote', pathMatch: 'full'},
       {path: 'vote', component: VoteComponent, data: {state: 'vote'}},
       {path: 'favorite-places', component: FavoritePlacesComponent, data: {state: 'favorite-places'}}
   ]}
 ]
},
```

Then the children should display in the appropriate router outlet.